# Output jquery function with two decimal places

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi:  I have the following jquery function but having trouble getting the result to come out with 2 decimal points. For example, if I have a value of 1 in the BadgeQuantity textbox, the output comes out at 50. I want it to come out as 50.00. Here is my function. As you can see, I have tried using .toFixed(2). Also tried using parseFloat and both not working.

```
$('input[name="BadgeQuantity"]').keyup(function(){
  var a = 50;
  var b = $(this).val();
  ($('input[name="BadgeTotal"]').val(a * b)).toFixed(2);
});
```

Thanks in advance for any help
cdr6800

Answer (score 1):

You almost have it -- you need to call `toFixed()` on the number not the DOM element. So change:

`($('input[name="BadgeTotal"]').val(a * b)).toFixed(2);`

To:

`$('input[name="BadgeTotal"]').val((a * b).toFixed(2));`

Answer (score 0):

Try to invoke `.toFixed()` over the arithmetic operation not over a Jquery object,

```
$('input[name="BadgeQuantity"]').keyup(function(){
  var a = 50;
  var b = $(this).val();
  $('input[name="BadgeTotal"]').val((a * b).toFixed(2));
});
```

`.toFixed()` is a function available in `Number`'s prototype. If we access it in Jquery wrapper object then will will results in an error `undefined is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

first: you should parse before assign to `b`

```
var b = parseFloat($(this).val());
```

next, you should use [`toFixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) on result multiply

```
$('input[name="BadgeTotal"]').val((a * b).toFixed(2));
```